# IIS Worker Process doing progress, but not responding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio Community Edition 2013, IIS 8.5, Windows 8.1

Somethimes I have to debug my Webapplication. So I attach my Visual Studio to worker process (w3wp.exe ... i think. I use AttachTo-Extension for Visual Studio).

Anyway, the first attach is successful and after terminating the debuging process i edit my code and compile it again. Then when i make a request to the webapplication it doesn't response.

I can find the workprocess in the taskmanger doing something because CPU Usage is about 15% 
[image: taskmanager]

If I kill the workerprocess then it will restart and everything is fine again.

Do anyone know whats the problem is?

Comment: Do you stop debugging before you edit? and after that can you build successfully?

Comment: yes, i stop before edit (I have to do). And compilation is successful after that.

Comment: Did you try to attach a process to it and pause the debugger to understand what the process is doing ?

Comment: good idea. I will try it next time

Comment: I didn't have this problem in the past weeks. I will refer to this thread when its happens again. Someone also recommanded me to reinstall the IIS Component. Maybe this could be a solution.

Comment: Same problem here with VS 2015 Community ... Any solution?